# Upload image not showing in Image View in Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, imageview, titanium, gallery

In table view I have items in row as image name, image view, upload from gallery button.

I have 16 rows in that.

For each row I clicked upload image from gallery button and select image then I put that image in to image view.

For first 4 rows it works fine. After that 5th row it shows as empty image view.

I tried many things but I can not find out what the exact problem is..

[these links for screen shots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy85ccbwm2s0pfi/Screenshot_2014-02-11-12-22-35.png)

Please find any solution for me.thank you in advance.

Code from comment:

```
var saveImageData = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(image, { width:480, height:360 });
if (saveImageData !== null) {
    var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification(
        { duration:1000, message:"save true "+saveImageData });
    toast.show();
} else {
    var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification(
        { duration:1000, message:"Problem" });
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: You won't get much help without showing some code.

Comment: `var saveImageData=ImageFactory.imageAsResized(image,{width:480,height:360});
                if(saveImageData!==null) {
                var toast=Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                            duration:1000,
                            message:"save true "+saveImageData
                        });
                        toast.show();
            }else{
                var toast=Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                        duration:1000,
                        message:"Problem"
                             });
                        toast.show();
            };`

Comment: in this above code some times i got null.whats is the reason for that?

Is it based on image size that we uploading?

if it is correct.. then for same size image its shows some times null,some times not null. whats is this problem.i cant able to handle this ImageFactory functionality.

please give any solution.because i stucked with this problem on my app.

Thanks all.

Comment: please see this bellow link.my problem is..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729912/imagefactory-imageasresized-returns-null